# Appending a single row to a DataFrame in Pandas 2.0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF as below. I have added a new column which has Total of all the rows and a new row which has total of all columns:

```
A  B  C   D   Total
-------------------
1  2   3   4   10
5  6   7   8   26
6  8  10  12   36
```

Now I need to add one more row for which the first element will be NaN and rest will be a column subtracted from the previous column in the Total row.

```
A B C D Total
1 2 3 4 10
5 6 7 8 26
6 8 10 12 36
NaN 2 2 2 24 <--- new row
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be one of the rare use cases for `df.append`, but in lieu of that you can extract the last row with [`iloc[-1]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) the individual values, then combine this back with the original.

**Option 1**
One method of doing this concatenation would be using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, df.iloc[-1].diff().to_frame().T])
print (df2) 

     A    B     C     D  Total
0  1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   10.0
1  5.0  6.0   7.0   8.0   26.0
2  6.0  8.0  10.0  12.0   36.0
2  NaN  2.0   2.0   2.0   24.0
```

Where,

```
df.iloc[-1].diff().to_frame().T # dataframe with 1 row

    A    B    C    D  Total
2 NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0   24.0
```

---

**Option 2**
An alternative using inplace assignment with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = df.iloc[-1].diff()
print (df)

     A    B     C     D  Total
0  1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   10.0
1  5.0  6.0   7.0   8.0   26.0
2  6.0  8.0  10.0  12.0   36.0
3  NaN  2.0   2.0   2.0   24.0
```

Where,

```
df.iloc[-1].diff()  # series

A         NaN
B         2.0
C         2.0
D         2.0
Total    24.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3**
Here's an option that has a bit of fun with dictionaries and `pd.DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame([*df.to_dict('records'), df.iloc[-1].diff().to_dict()])

     A    B     C     D  Total
0 1.00 2.00  3.00  4.00  10.00
1 5.00 6.00  7.00  8.00  26.00
2 6.00 8.00 10.00 12.00  36.00
3  NaN 2.00  2.00  2.00  24.00
```

---

**Option 4 [deprecated]**
On older versions (pandas <= 1.4) I would have recommended using `append` like this:

```
df2 = df.append(df.iloc[-1].diff(), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I also need to get the %change calculated in the same way. for example: from 6 to 8 will be (8-6)*100/6

Comment: df.iloc[-1].pct_change() gave me the desired result